# BS4: Getting text in tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup. There is a tag like this:

`<li><a href="example"> s.r.o., <small>small</small></a></li>`

I want to get the text within the anchor `<a>` tag only, without any from the `<small>` tag in the output; i.e. " *`s.r.o.,`* "

I tried `find('li').text[0]` but it does not work.

Is there a command in BS4 which can do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One option would be to get the first element from the [`contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) of the `a` element:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '<li><a href="example"> s.r.o., <small>small</small></a></li>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> print soup.find('a').contents[0]
 s.r.o.,
```

Another one would be to find the `small` tag and get the [previous sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
>>> print soup.find('small').previous_sibling
 s.r.o.,
```

---

Well, there are all sorts of alternative/crazy options also:

```
>>> print next(soup.find('a').descendants)
 s.r.o., 
>>> print next(iter(soup.find('a')))
 s.r.o.,
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.children](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

```
soup.find('a').children.next()
s.r.o.,
```

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know, split() without argument use ' ' as separator which is in this very case useful but there are cases when spaces and commas are contained in this text so it won't works. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right I will have a look when I get back on my comp in a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to loop to print all content of anchor tags located in html string/web page (must utilise urlopen from urllib), this works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = '<li><a href="example">s.r.o., <small>small</small</a></li> <li><a href="example">2nd</a></li> <li><a href="example">3rd</a></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
a_tag=soup('a')
for tag in a_tag:
    print(tag.contents[0])     #.contents method to locate text within <a> tags
```

Output:

```
s.r.o.,  
2nd
3rd
```

`a_tag` is a list containing all anchor tags; collecting all anchor tags in a list, enables group editing (if more than one `<a>` tags present.

```
>>>print(a_tag)
[<a href="example">s.r.o.,  <small>small</small></a>, <a href="example">2nd</a>, <a href="example">3rd</a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, retrieving the text of the tag can be done by calling string property

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<li><a href="example"> s.r.o., <small>small</small></a></li>')
res = soup.find('a')
res.small.decompose()
print(res.string)
# s.r.o.,
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring