# How to get 2 different classes text in a div

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a web scraping using Python and BeautifulSoup, but I hit a wall. Here is the original page markup:

```
 <div class="name">target 1<div class="date">updated 25th January 2019</div></div>
```

I need just the first part ("target 1")

I tried to find the class "name" with

```
mgroup[0].a.findAll("div",{"class":"name"})
```

or

```
mgroup[0].a.findAll("div",)[1].div
```

but it always returns

```
<div class="name">target 1<div class="date">updated 25th January 2019</div></div>
```

but if I use the class "date" like this

```
mgroup[0].a.findAll("div",{"class":{"date"})
```

I get:

```
<div class="date">updated 25th January 2019</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is because the div is inside a unclosed div or if the tag "name" might be a reserved term or something similar even tried

```
mgroup[0].a.findAll("div",{"class":["name"}])
```

with same result

```
  [<div class="name">target 1<div class="date">updated 25th January 2019</div></div>]
```

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returning the BS4 element itself. You can access the contents of the element like this:

```
hit = mgroup[0].a.findAll("div",{"class":"name"})
print(hit.contents[0])
```

Comment: this just gets a "clean" text with both target and date , and what i need is to get just the target

Comment: and the print(type(hit)) result   <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251841/bs4-getting-text-in-tag ... so maybe try ```hit.contents[0]```

Comment: Ah, excellent. Updated the original answer with that contents bit.