# Using BS4 - how to get text only, and not tags?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page on medicine and the market asset for some companies on https://www.formularylookup.com/

Below code gets me the desired data as in Number of plans, which pharmacies are covering the medicine, and the status in %. Here is an example of my output, where the desired output would just be "1330 plans":

Number of plans:

```
<td class="plan-count" role="gridcell">1330 plans</td>
```

I have tried using .text after each tag.find, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code concerning this specific part. There's a whole lot more going on above, but it includes log in information I cannot share.

```py
total = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all("tbody", {"role":"rowgroup"}):
    #name = tag.find("td", {"class":"payer-name"}) #gives me whole tag
    name = tag.find("tr", {"role":"row"}).find("td").get("payer-name") #gives me None output
    plan = tag.find("td", {"class":"plan-count"})  #gives me whole tag
    stat = tag.find("td", {"class":"icon-status"}) #gives me whole tag

    data = {"Payer": name, "Number of plans": plan, "Status": stat}

    total.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(total)
print(df)
```

Here is a snippet using the inspect function.

```html
<tbody role="rowgroup">
    <tr data-uid="a5795205-1518-4a74-b039-abcd1b35b409" role="row">
        <td class="payer-name" role="gridcell">CVS Caremark RX</td>
        <td class="plan-count" role="gridcell">1330 plans</td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="icon-status icon-status-not-covered">98% Not Covered</td>
     </tr>
```

EDIT: After diving deeper into SO I see a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251841/bs4-getting-text-in-tag?rq=1) could be using the Contents function of BS4. Will report back if it works.
- This didn't work: 
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'"

Comment: perhaps I could use the contents function?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently there are other tags starting with tbody rowgroup further above, which are classified as None, and therefore it is not possible to get .text of these, until my code reaches the parts I want.

I just need to change this line:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("tbody", {"role":"rowgroup"}):
```

Comment: I still seem to get 1 empty row, being the first one. I need to figure out how to get rid of it, until then .text will not work.